# C++ Define function of external namespace inside of nested namespace

Tags: c++, syntax, namespaces, syntax-error, argument-dependent-lookup

Consider the code

```
namespace A
{    
}

namespace B
{
    namespace ::A
    {
        void func();
    }
}
```

This is invalid C++ syntax - but I'm looking for something that works. I need to declare ::A::func(), but from within namespace B (I don't want B::A::func, but A::func).

(If you ask why? then it is because func() will eventually by declared by a macro that also declares some things in namespace B.)

Is is possible?

Comment: Close namespace B before declaring `func` in namespace A then close namespace A and then reopen namespace B.

Comment: My project has that need.  We solved it by having two macros, one for referencing in the other namespace, and the other for declaring that thing in the right namespace.  (I hate macros.)

Comment: @RichardCritten That's why I would normally do if writing code manually. But this is supposed be in macro as universal solution. E.g. it could be A::B::C - I don't know how many namespaces there are. I guess it's not possible then.

Comment: @Eljay Currently I've done the same, was just wondering if there's a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

No it's not possible to somehow reset yourself to the global namespace within the scope of another namespace, for the purpose of declarations.

It could be useful on occasions though and C++ does pride itself on being a general purpose language, although it would make source code confusing to read as having used `namespace ::A` you are no longer in `namespace B` despite the source code telling you otherwise! If you *really* want to see this then why not propose it to the standards committee?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `using` declaration. For example

```
namespace A
{
    void func();    
}

namespace B
{
    using A::func;
}
```

Then for example in the global namespace you can write

```
void other_func()
{
    B::func();
}
```